# Can't open config.json

Tags: json, node.js

**Snippet**

```
// Load config
var config = fs.readFile('../config/config.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  config = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

**Error:**

```
/Users/jensgryspeert/Documents/STAGE/Raspberry Rest API/config/initializers/server.js:11
  if (err) throw err;
           ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../config/config.json'
    at Error (native)
```

The location of the snippet is in: *config/initializers/server.js*

The location of the config.json file is in: *config/config.json*

I doesn't understand why it's not finding the json config file.
Also an extra question just for information. Is it possible to just require('../config.json'); Without the reading FS package?

Comment: please paste the exact error you are getting!
for you 2nd question..yes that is possible if your config.json contains valid json.

Comment: @waza007: I've updated the begin post. Thanks for the second question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be sure to get your file, you should use [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html). This variable will have the value of the absolute path to the folder where your current js file is, so in your case, for `server.js`, `[absolutepathtoyourproject]/config/initializers/`.

So you can have the right path using node's [path library](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html):

```
var path = require('path');
var pathToJson = path.resolve(__dirname, '../config.json');

// Load config
var config = fs.readFile(pathToJson , 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    config = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

And if it does not find the file, at least you have the pathToJson variable to help you see why the path is not good.

Concerning your second question, it is possible, and recommended as you would avoid the trouble of reading and parsing the file. You could even store it in a js file named for instance `config.js` as

```
var config = { /* your config here */ };

module.exports = config;
```

And in your server.js file, if you have the same file hierarchy, you can do:

```
var config = require('../config.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

make that like this.And see it works.

```
var config = fs.readFile('../config.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    config = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

or You can do like this.

```
var config = require('../config.json');
console.log(config);
```

Comment: /Users/jensgryspeert/Documents/STAGE/Raspberry Rest API/config/initializers/server.js:11
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../../config.json'
    at Error (native)

Comment: Either I tought the ../ is go 1 folder back. So normally I went from /config/initializers => /config. That's what I thought must be possible to open the /config/config.json file

Comment: the error is with the path only since it is not found!

Comment: With the absolute path it works. Otherwise for some reason he doesn't find the file

Comment: Update the code!

make sure after changing '../config.json' you save the server.js file and then run.